# Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?

Tags: x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run Image application from server "bert"

I connected through my OSX Maverick as

```
ssh ak324@bert.eecs.qmul.ac.uk
```

I compiled my file with

```
$ make
```

but when I run the resulting file

$ ./window

it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You should connect with the -X or -Y option to be able to launch graphical applications:

```
ssh -X ak324@bert.eecs.qmul.ac.uk
```

If that doesn't help, you should consult /etc/ssh/sshd_config whether X11Forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in Putty?

Comment: Just check "Enable X11 Forwarding" in Putty under Connection / SSH / X11.

Comment: Did it, and still getting `Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?`

Answer (score 1):

On macOS you need to install [xquartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) for x11 support https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201341.

Then you can connect with

```
ssh -Y ak324@bert.eecs.qmul.ac.uk
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running ssh with the flags `-Y -v`.

If the following line appears on the terminal during the ssh connection, install `xauth` on your remote system.

`debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.`

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961495/x11-forwarding-request-failed-on-channel-0#42735336).