# Unable to do X11 forwarding

Tags: x11-forwarding

I have a AWS server running SUSE and I am trying to forward X11
but I am getting this error.

```
17:46:41: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
 SAP HANA Installer Runtime Error: perl compilation error (loading 

LCM::Gui::App::LCMGuiApp): cannot load wxWidgets properly: cannot open display 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at SDB/Install/App/Gui.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at LCM/Gui/App/LCMGuiApp.pm line 6.
```

I already opened putty with X11 forwarding enabled and also have xming installed on my desktop running and also set the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: Not a programming question per se.

Comment: I'm not one to flag so I won't but someone should migrate this question to the right community.  Maybe they can help you there.

Comment: yes agree with u, initially tot so too, but then tot since this is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878489/error-unable-to-initialize-gtk-is-display-set-properly